# Kubernetes Job scheduling

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for the following features in Kubernetes but unable to find  documentation in this regards.

1. Running a child Job after parent job(s) gets completed.
2. Disabling Job for a while - Disabling/Enabling feature
3. Manual Job triggering - If job needs to triggered manually for any reason
4. Job Failure notification - Email notification or invoking an end point on a Job failure
5. Is there any way to listen to Job status or getting Job history thru REST API?

Thanks

Comment: #1 doesn't exist (AFAIK), #2 is just deleting/recreating the job, #3 what do you mean by "manual"?, #4 doesn't exist (AFAIK).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean my Job scheduling? **CronJob**? If yes

_2. You can disable scheduling new Job

```
Suspend: true
// This flag tells the controller to suspend subsequent executions, it does
// not apply to already started executions.
```

Set Suspend field to be `true`.

```
PATCH /apis/batch/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/cronjobs/{name}
// You need to patch in correct format
{  
   "spec":{  
      "suspend":"true"
   }
}
```

_5. You can also get CronJob status. There you will find information about success/failure

```
GET /apis/batch/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/cronjobs/{name}/status
```

> [1,3,4] these are not supported

Comment: So, Can I suspend a Job for a while and enable again? Is there any REST API for this?

Comment: Yes, you can. I will update post

Comment: check now. updated aanswer